How to pass custom types data like settings in a Prismic Slice?
In Prismic templates, there is often a page called Settings that is a Custom type, where you can set some global datas of your website like Site name, logo, mail ...
I'm trying to use the settings in a Slice to have an email address dynamically populate, but it doesn't work. Also, my slice is a client component, because I'm using states and hooks inside.
The problems I meet is :

as a client component I can't use async await
even in a server component, createClient asks me for arguments I don't understand

What is the best way to get those datas inside a slice?
My slice :
"use client";

import { useState } from "react";
import { Bounded } from "@/components/Bounded";
import { Heading } from "@/components/Heading";
import { Content } from "@prismicio/client";
import {
  JSXMapSerializer,
  PrismicRichText,
  SliceComponentProps,
} from "@prismicio/react";
import clsx from "clsx";
import { Link, useDisclosure } from "@nextui-org/react"; // Utilisation de useDisclosure
import PricingModal from "@/components/PricingModal";

/**
 * Props for `PricingCards`.
 */
export type PricingCardsProps = SliceComponentProps<Content.PricingCardsSlice>;

/**
 * Component for "PricingCards" Slices.
 */
const PricingCards = ({ slice }: PricingCardsProps): JSX.Element => {
  const { isOpen, onOpen, onClose } = useDisclosure(); // Gestion d'ouverture avec NextUI
  const [modalContent, setModalContent] = useState<React.ReactNode>(null);
  const handleOpen = (content: JSX.Element) => {
    setModalContent(content); // Définit le contenu à afficher dans le modal
    onOpen(); // Ouvre le modal
  };

  if (slice.variation === "fullWidth") {
    const { title, subtitle, moreinfo, price, color } = slice.primary;

    const components: JSXMapSerializer = {
      heading4: ({ children }) => (
        <Heading as="h3" size="md" className="first:mt-0 last:mb-0">
          {children}
        </Heading>
      ),
      heading2: ({ children }) => (
        <Heading as="h2" size="xl" className="first:mt-0 last:mb-0">
          {children}
        </Heading>
      ),
      heading3: ({ children }) => (
        <Heading as="h2" size="lg" className="first:mt-0 last:mb-0">
          {children}
        </Heading>
      ),
    };

    return (
      <Bounded as="section" yPadding="none">
        <div
          className={clsx(
            "flex flex-col items-center text-beige gap-2 lg:gap-5 transition duration-500 rounded-lg p-5 mb-4 lg:mb-6 hover:shadow-xl hover:bg-red",
            {
              "bg-keppel": color === "keppel",
              "bg-secondary": color === "secondary",
              "bg-primary": color === "primary",
            }
          )}
          onClick={() =>
            handleOpen(
              <div className="flex flex-col gap-5 p-10 text-center">
                <div>
                  <div className="flex gap-5 font-semibold justify-center">
                    <p className="text-5xl">{title}</p>
                    <p className="text-5xl">{price}</p>
                  </div>
                  <p className="text-2xl">{subtitle}</p>
                </div>
                <p className="text-3xl">{moreinfo}</p>
                <button className="relative mx-auto py-3 px-5 mt-8 rounded-3xl overflow-hidden bg-transparent text-beige border-beige border-2 transition-all duration-200 before:absolute before:bottom-0 before:left-0 before:right-0 before:top-0 before:m-auto before:h-full before:w-0 before:rounded-sm before:bg-lightBlue before:duration-300 before:ease-out hover:shadow-sm hover:text-primary hover:bg-transparent hover:shadow-lightBlue hover:before:h-40 hover:before:w-full hover:before:opacity-100">
                  <span className="z-10 relative">
                    <Link
                      href=""
                      className="text-base lg:text-xl text-beige font-semibold"
                    >
                      Obtenez votre devis personnalisé
                    </Link>
                  </span>
                </button>{" "}
              </div>
            )
          } // Ouvre le modal avec la description
        >
          <div>
            {title && (
              <h2 className="text-3xl lg:text-6xl text-center leading-none">
                {title}
              </h2>
            )}
            {subtitle && (
              <h2 className="text-xl lg:text-3xl text-center">{subtitle}</h2>
            )}
          </div>
          {price && (
            <p className="text-3xl lg:text-6xl font-semibold text-center">
              {price}
            </p>
          )}
        </div>

        {/* Utilisation du Modal commun */}
        <PricingModal isOpen={isOpen} onClose={onClose} size="5xl">
          <div>{modalContent}</div>
        </PricingModal>
      </Bounded>
    );
  }

  // Gestion de la variante Default
  const data: Content.PricingCardsSliceDefaultPrimaryDataItem[] =
    slice.primary.data || [];

  return (
    <Bounded as="section" yPadding="none">
      <div className="grid grid-cols-3 gap-4">
        {data.map((item, index) => (
          <div
            key={index}
            className="flex flex-col justify-center gap-5 transition duration-500 hover:shadow-xl hover:bg-red leading-none font-semibold p-5 items-center bg-keppel text-beige rounded-lg cursor-pointer"
            onClick={() =>
              handleOpen(
                <div className="flex flex-col p-10 gap-5 items-center text-center justify-center">
                  <div className="flex items-center gap-3">
                    <p className="text-5xl font-semibold">{item.duration}</p>
                    <span className="text-5xl">I</span>
                    <p className="text-5xl font-semibold">{item.price} €</p>
                  </div>
                  <p className="text-3xl">{item.moreinfo}</p>
                  <div className=" mt-8 w-2/3">
                    <p className="text-2xl font-semibold">
                      Votre chien ne peut pas sortir pour raisons médicales ou
                      autres?
                    </p>
                    <p className="text-xl font-normal">
                      Nous proposons également des visites pour prendre soin de
                      lui. Au programme : câlins, jeux, sortie dans le jardin...
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  <button className="relative mx-auto py-3 px-5 mt-8 rounded-3xl overflow-hidden bg-transparent text-beige border-beige border-2 transition-all duration-200 before:absolute before:bottom-0 before:left-0 before:right-0 before:top-0 before:m-auto before:h-full before:w-0 before:rounded-sm before:bg-lightBlue before:duration-300 before:ease-out hover:shadow-sm hover:text-primary hover:bg-transparent hover:shadow-lightBlue hover:before:h-40 hover:before:w-full hover:before:opacity-100">
                    <span className="z-10 relative">
                      <Link
                        href=""
                        className="text-base lg:text-xl text-beige font-semibold"
                      >
                        Obtenez votre devis personnalisé
                      </Link>
                    </span>
                  </button>
                </div>
              )
            } // Ouvre le modal avec des infos spécifiques
          >
            {item.duration && (
              <div className="text-xl lg:text-5xl">{item.duration}*</div>
            )}
            {item.price && (
              <div className="flex items-start">
                <div className="text-2xl lg:text-8xl">{item.price} €</div>
                <span className="text-xl lg:text-5xl">**</span>
              </div>
            )}
            <div className="text-sm lg:text-xl">Plus d&apos;info</div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>

      <div className="p-5 mt-3 mb-4 lg:mt-4 lg:mb-6 w-full flex-col transition duration-500 justify-between hover:bg-red text-beige bg-keppel rounded-lg items-center gap-5 inline-flex cursor-pointer">
        <div className="self-stretch leading-none text-center text-2xl lg:text-5xl ">
          Abonnement mensuel possible avec tarifs préférentiels
        </div>
        <a
          href="mailto:"
          className="text-white text-xl lg:text-3xl font-medium"
        >
          Nous contacter
        </a>
      </div>

      {/* Utilisation du Modal commun */}
      <PricingModal isOpen={isOpen} onClose={onClose} size="5xl">
        <div>{modalContent}</div>
      </PricingModal>
    </Bounded>
  );
};

export default PricingCards;

